# Average Price and Percentage Gain

Tags: investing, calculation, shares, price, value-averaging

I am finding hard to arrive at the average price when there is a sell happened at much profitable price partially

Could you please advice me to arrive at the average price and the % gain for the below scenario ?

[image]

Comment: I have to ask - I can glance at this, see an average cost of $4000, and sales of $7000. What have you tried, and where are you having an issue? 4 to 7 is a 75% gain on sales so far.

Answer (score 1):

Adding holding and value to your table

```
#   Price   Flow    Held  Value
3   4000    12000   3     12000
20  4000    80000   23    92000
10  7000   -70000   13    91000
10  7000   -70000   3     21000
1   7000    -7000   2     14000
```

the [time-weighted return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-weighted_return#Time-Weighted_Return_Compensating_for_External_Flows) can be calculated

```
(92-80)/12*(91+70)/92*(21+70)/91*(14+7)/21-1 = 75%
```